# miniconda doesn't install the specific version of python in virtual env

Tags: python, anaconda, ubuntu-18.04, miniconda

I use the command `conda create -n test python=3.7` and then I run `conda activate test`
in the `test` env, when I type `python` command , it still run the system default python version which under `/usr/bin/python`

I try to reinstall the miniconda so many times, but still get this problem
My OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Here are the screenshot of installation progress and terminal

[installation progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csIhM.png)
[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97VUU.png)

Comment: Nothing is wrong with you commands. How do you know which python is enabled? Do you see something like`(test) user@user:~$` in in terminal after you run `conda activate test`?

Comment: yes i see (test)in my terminal,but when I type which python or directly run python command, both show the system version

Comment: I even check the installation progress of test env,  it did install the correct version of python, but cannot invoke it

Comment: What does `type python` give you? what does `echo $PATH` contain after the activation of `test`?